# Is there a way I could select a song from the FileListView (by click), load it to the Soundloader and play it with the PLAY button?

Tags: python, kivy, mp3, audio-player

#So this is a simple mp3 player I'm trying to make on python/kivy. I'm using FileListView to display my mp3 files. Is there a way I could select a song from the FileListView (by click), load it to the Soundloader and play it with the PLAY button?#

```
        import os  
        import kivy  
        from kivy.app import App  
        from kivy.uix.button import Button  
        from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout  
        from kivy.uix.label import Label  
        from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout  
        from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout  
        from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage  
        from kivy.uix.filechooser import FileChooserListView  
        from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader  
        from kivy.loader import Loader  
        from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager  


           def callback(instance):  
               print('The button <%s> is being pressed' % instance.text)  


             red = [1, 0, 0, 1]  
             green = [0, 1, 0, 1]  
             blue = [0, 0, 1, 1]  
             purple = [1, 0, 1, 1]  


        class myLayout(BoxLayout):  

             color = [red, green, blue, purple]  

             path = '/home/edward/Music'  


           def __init__(self, **kwargs):  
             super(myLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)  

             layout = BoxLayout(pos=self.pos, size=self.size,spacing=10)  

            self.add_widget(layout)  

            flc = FileChooserListView(path='/home/edward/Music',filters=['*.mp3'],size=(7, 3))  
            flc.bind(on_selection=self.load_sound)  

             layout.add_widget(flc)  

        # creating the play button  

            play = Button(text="PLAY",valign='center', halign='center',background_color=blue,size_hint=(0.3, 0.5))  

              play.bind(on_press=self.play_pressed)  
              layout.add_widget(play)  

        # creating the stop button  

              stop = Button(text="STOP", valign='center',halign='center',size_hint=(0.3, 0.6),background_color=red)  
              layout.add_widget(stop)  
              stop.bind(on_press=self.stop_pressed)  

        #creating a Label  

             display=Label(text="kiwiAudioPlayer",halign='right', size=(3,5))

             layout.add_widget(display)  

        #displaying an animated image  

         animate = AsyncImage(source='https://i.gifer.com/KNGq.gif',                              allow_stretch=False, anim_delay=0.10)  

              layout.add_widget(animate)  

        #trying to define a load song function  

           def load_sound(self, filename):

                sound = FileChooserListView.selection(self.path)
              with open(os.path.join(self.path, filename[0])):
                if sound is None:
                    sound = SoundLoader.load(self.path)
                if sound.status != 'stop':
                    sound.stop()
   
                    sound.play()
 
         #play button function

           def play_pressed(self, sound, play):  

                sound = SoundLoader.load(self.path)  
                if sound is None:  
                    sound.play()  

      #stop button function  

           def stop_pressed(self, sound, stop):  

                sound = SoundLoader.unload(self.path)  
                sound.stop()  

#main function

      class musicApp(App):  

           def build(self):  

              return myLayout()  

   if __name__ == "__main__":  
           app = musicApp()  
           app.run()
```

#so the question is how can I actually combine the Filelistview and the Soundloader modules so that I can click on a song from the list and play it instantly?

Comment: I'm a junior and really new to python so... any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few modifications gets your code working. First, your binding of the filechooser `selection` should use the property name, like ths:

```
flc.bind(selection=self.load_sound)
```

Then, making an instance variable to hold the sound makes it simpler to handle. Here is a modified version of your code with those changes:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage
from kivy.uix.filechooser import FileChooserListView
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader


def callback(instance):
   print('The button <%s> is being pressed' % instance.text)


red = [1, 0, 0, 1]
green = [0, 1, 0, 1]
blue = [0, 0, 1, 1]
purple = [1, 0, 1, 1]


class myLayout(BoxLayout):

    color = [red, green, blue, purple]
    path = '/home/edward/Music'


    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(myLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.sound = None

        layout = BoxLayout(pos=self.pos, size=self.size,spacing=10)

        self.add_widget(layout)

        flc = FileChooserListView(path='/home/edward/Music',filters=['*.mp3'],size=(7, 3))
        flc.bind(selection=self.load_sound)  # bind to the property `selection`

        layout.add_widget(flc)

        # creating the play button

        play = Button(text="PLAY",valign='center', halign='center',background_color=blue,size_hint=(0.3, 0.5))

        play.bind(on_press=self.play_pressed)
        layout.add_widget(play)

        # creating the stop button

        stop = Button(text="STOP", valign='center',halign='center',size_hint=(0.3, 0.6),background_color=red)
        layout.add_widget(stop)
        stop.bind(on_press=self.stop_pressed)

        #creating a Label

        display=Label(text="kiwiAudioPlayer",halign='right', size=(3,5))

        layout.add_widget(display)

        #displaying an animated image

        animate = AsyncImage(source='https://i.gifer.com/KNGq.gif',                              allow_stretch=False, anim_delay=0.10)

        layout.add_widget(animate)

    #trying to define a load song function

    def load_sound(self, filechooser, selection):

        # sound = FileChooserListView.selection(self.path)
        # with open(os.path.join(self.path, filename[0])):
        #     if sound is None:
        #         sound = SoundLoader.load(self.path)
        #     if sound.status != 'stop':
        #         sound.stop()
        if self.sound is not None:
            self.sound.stop()
        self.sound = SoundLoader.load(selection[0])

    #play button function

    def play_pressed(self, button):

        # sound = SoundLoader.load(self.path)
        # if sound is None:
        #     sound.play()
        if self.sound is not None:
            self.sound.play()

    #stop button function

    def stop_pressed(self, button):

        # sound = SoundLoader.unload(self.path)
        # sound.stop()
        if self.sound is not None:
            self.sound.stop()

#main function

class musicApp(App):

   def build(self):

      return myLayout()

if __name__ == "__main__":
       app = musicApp()
       app.run()
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help Mr. Anderson! I hope at least I made you laugh with the irrelevant lines of code that you had to comment. :-)

Comment: Now that I'm reviewing it again..  the property name mistake in the filechooser assignment was just plain stupidity but apart from that I learned a lot today.  thanks again